# Dynamically add a User Control to a page without page postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I want to add a user control to my pages without page post backs.

I can't use Update Panels because I have file uploads control in the user controls.

I also don't want to put the custom controls in a page and then load it inside a page using jQuery load functions. Similarly I cannot use iframes.

How can I do it through some jQuery or AJAX?

Comment: You cannot add a control without registering it to the page's control collection, which is initialized on the server before the page is actually rendered, so if you really need a .net control (and not a simple html input tag) you have to make either a full or a partial postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is posted by some user but he/she has removed the answer:

So i am posting his answer

Though i want to add a server controls in my application but i left with no choice except to use HTML Elements

```
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(b));
    UserControl u = new Page().LoadControl("~/UserControl.ascx") as UserControl;
    u.RenderControl(h);

    return b.ToString();
```

This works only if all the controls in a USER CONTROL is of html type